# Why won't my PHP script upload video files?

Tags: php

This PHP script works perfectly for audio files, but when I changed it to handle video files, it keeps sending me the "This is not allowed error". Here is my code:

```
$file = $_POST['filev'];

            $fileName = $_FILES['filev']['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['filev']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['filev']['size'];
            $fileError = $_FILES['filev']['error'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['filev']['type'];

            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

            $allowed = array('mp4', 'MP4', 'mpeg', 'wmv', 'ogg', 'webM', 'mov', 'swf');

            if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
                if ($fileError === 0) {
                    if ($fileSize < 75000000000000000) {
                        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

                        //insert post
                        $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO posts 
VALUES('', '$fileDestination', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 
'no', '0')");

                        $returned_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);

                        //update post count for user
                        $num_posts = $this->user_obj->getNumPosts();
                        $num_posts++;
                        $update_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE 
users SET num_posts='$num_posts' WHERE username='$added_by'");



                        header("Location: video.php?success");

                    } else {
                        echo "Your file is too big";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "There was an error uploading your file";
                }
            }
             else {
                echo "This is not allowed";
            }
```

The file I have been trying to upload is an mp4 file, but it still gives me that "This is not allowed error", even though I have it included in the $allowed variable. Any help towards my problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you print out `$fileActualExt ` to check that it is indeed `mp4`?

Comment: yes I did, it is an mp4

Comment: Can you please add `var_dump($fileActualExt);` directly after `$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));` and post what is displayed **exactly** how it is shown?

Comment: Also, it's odd that your `$allowed` array contains strings with uppercase characters considering you use `strtolower()` on the string to check

Comment: It printed out this: string(0) ""

Answer (score -1):

Try putting an .flv on the $allowed variable